# Cannot connect to (localdb)\v11.0

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I just installed SQL server management  2016 as my 2014 version had stopped working when I went from Win 7 to Win 10. Now My Localdb is completly stuffed... When I go into server management I cannot log into (localdb)\v11.0 any more :(
Also VS2015 cannot inspect the mdf when I double click on it, it gives me: "A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server....."

By the way, when I uninstalled the old Managment studio 2015 It didn't want to uninstall because it had become janky... So I had to manually Delete the folders.. I say folders as there were 2 SQL Server managment folders in 2 of my program file locations (diferent HDD's) also during the install of Server managment 2016 It failed heaps of time because it couldn't apply a service update to VS2010. VS2010 was also half uninstalled due to jankynes caused by Win7 -> Win10. So I had to try and uninstal VS2010, but it wouldn't because it was missing a disk, so I downloaded the iso and removed it.

Sorry if this is a bit of a mouthfull, but I'm going to be offline for 10hrs so I wanted to put as much info as possible to helpe people help me :)

Thanks in advance,
Michael.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720317/606007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I managed to find a download to LocalDB 2014 (sorry I don't have the link atm, if your having this issue too please comment and I'll find the download source) which after restarting my system fix it.