# How do I get my Blazor app to see my local SQL Server for authentication?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, blazor, sql-default-instance

I'm starting with a vanilla Blazor app in Visual Studio 16.3.7 with authentication:
[image]

I go to the Register page:
[image]

I fill in the email and password fields, click the Register button, and after a long think it fails with this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Win32Exception: Unknown error (0x89c50118)
>   Unknown location
>   SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   )
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling, string accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>   Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
>   Win32Exception: Unknown error (0x89c50118)
>   Show raw exception details ...

When I go to my Windows Event Viewer, the following error seems relevant:
[image]

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: I know  vanilla ice-cream,  vanilla JavaScript, but what do you mean by  vanilla Blazor ? Your app cannot be but Blazor Server as authentication is not enabled for Blazor WebAssembly, right ? Please, what is the structure of your ailing app ?

Comment: Issac, Vanilla is a perfectly fine idiom. Plain vanilla would be an oxymoron.

Comment: @hal, what version of localdb is installed?   Open the "Sql Server Object Explorer" window and open the SQl item. Mine says `(SQL Server 13.0.4001) ` and that works fine. I see 12E in your error msgs, that looks like a version.

Comment: "Sql Server Object Explorer"  shows (SQL Server 14.0.2027).

Comment: Yes, that 14.0 is visible in the screenshots. And it's not an issue of VS 16.3.7, it runs fine on my PC.

Comment: Google the error, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022742/ and a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Registry Editor to delete the UserInstances key with the older ParentInstance. Now my registry looks like this: [image]

And I'm getting a different error in my Blazor app.

Thank you Henk for pointing me in the right direction!