# login failed for user [MyUserName] , when I run my windows form app

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I made a windows form app witch uses sql server as it's database . In my own system, my app is working great with no errors but when I run it in another system it gives me the error - "login failed for user [MyUserName]"

Also I used sql authentication to attach to my database

Here is my connection string

```
    string connectionSt = "Initial Catalog = IndustryContracts; Uid=****;Pwd=****";
```

Comment: is the database maybe setup for windows authentication only?

Comment: No it is SQL server and windows Authentication mode

Comment: Unless this is a contained database, you need to create the SQL login `Feri` and make sure it's properly mapped after the attach with `ALTER USER Feri WITH LOGIN = Feri;`

Comment: The connection string doesn't mention a server. Where's it meant to be connecting to?

Comment: instead of server I used my database name.

Comment: <add name="default" connectionString="Server=server-name;Database=databasenamel;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;Encrypt=False;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

Witch you Database use ? MS Sql Server Or LocalDb ?

**LocalDb:** must change connection string after publish [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62052743/12777835)

---

**Sql Server:** you mus install MS Sql server each PC you want install your app and Resturn your database

> I Suggest you use **sa** user for Login Sql server in connectionString,
> [Enable sa user](https://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I used sql server as localDB.

Comment: for localDb not use User and change your app config like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62052743/12777835 

use LocalDb in WinForm C# ==> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/use-local-database-file-in-window-application-C-Sharp/